# gfortran -std=f2008 compile flag errors if call fseek present

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to enforce a Fortran 2008 consistency check with gfortran.  When I compile with -std=f2008, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fseek_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccJtOcKa.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The following simple test program shows the issue.  It compiles and runs fine without the -std=f2008, but doesn't compile when this flag is set.

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  open(unit=10, file='test.bin', access='stream')
  write(10) 100

  !fseek works, but will not compile with -std=f2008
  call fseek(10, -4, 1)
  read(10) i
  print *, i
end program
```

This works:
`gfortran main.f90`

This gives the error:
`gfortran -std=f2008 main.f90`

I'm using MacPorts version of gfortran 8.2

```
GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc8 8.2.0_3) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is fseek not a part of the fortran 2008 standard?  If so, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: `fseek` is [not F2008](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html#FSEEK).  If you want to catch the error earlier (before linking) you can try adding an `intrinsic fseek` statement early on.

Comment: If you open the manual, it clearly says it is a "GNU extension" (in case of the GNU compiler) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FSEEK` an an extension intrinsic subroutine which is unnecessary for stream access. You can just read from any position you want

```
read(10, pos=42) i
```

You can also get the current position with the `inquire` statement.

```
inquire(unit=10, pos=current_pos)
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have indicated, `FSEEK` is not in a Fortran standard.  The Fortran standard does, however, permit a processor to supply additional intrinsics subprograms.  To avoid the problem you are having, you can use the `-fall-intrinsics` option.  Thus, `gfortran -std=f2008 -fall-intrinsics` will try to adhere to the Fortran 2008 standard with the exceptional that all intrinsic subprograms supplied by gfortran are available.